# Dictionary.ContainsKey misbehave c#

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I've got a class `Column`

```
public class Column
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public EPersonalCharacteristicType Type { get; private set; }
    public Column MainColumn { get; private set; }
}
```

and I've got the following field in another class

```
Dictionary<Column, string> dictionary
```

In the middle of execution I get a strange behavior of this `dictionary`. When I typed

```
dictionary.ContainsKey(dictionary.Keys.ToList()[1])
```

I got `false`.
How on Earth can it be?

**UPDATED**
my `Column` class has GetHashCode or Equals Functions. Here are the implementations of them:

```
public bool Equals(Column other)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
    if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
    return other.Id == Id && Equals(other.Name, Name) && Equals(other.Type, Type) && Equals(other.MainColumn, MainColumn) && Equals(other.childColumns, childColumns);
}

public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
    if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
    if (obj.GetType() != typeof (Column)) return false;
    return Equals((Column) obj);
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    unchecked
    {
        int result = Id;
        result = (result*397) ^ (Name != null ? Name.GetHashCode() : 0);
        result = (result*397) ^ Type.GetHashCode();
        result = (result*397) ^ (MainColumn != null ? MainColumn.GetHashCode() : 0);
        result = (result*397) ^ (childColumns != null ? childColumns.GetHashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}

public static bool operator ==(Column left, Column right)
{
    return Equals(left, right);
}

public static bool operator !=(Column left, Column right)
{
    return !Equals(left, right);
}
```

Comment: Does `Column` override `GetHashCode` and/or `Equals`?

Comment: Just to double-check: you're definitely getting `false` and not an exception thrown, for example, the dictionary definitely contains at least 2 entries (`[1]` meaning the second key in the list)?

Comment: A short test in LINQPad couldn't reproduce this. I suggest you provide a complete working sample, that allows to reproduce this behavior.

Comment: Did you override `Equals` and/or `GetHashCode` on `Column`? If yes you most likely overrode them incorrectly causing this problem.

Comment: Is column immutable? Or does it at least not change while it's added to the dictionary? Else that's your problem.

Comment: And I hope you did not derive any classes from Column. Since for those your code will break. I recommend making `Column` sealed.

Comment: @StuffHappens, not sure about childColumns because its not mentioned anywhere (probably a column i assume) but you should have a look at my answer with regards to your equals method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a general problem but something specific to your code.

**UPDATE:**
The hash code of the key of a dictionary must not change. This is not the case with your `Column` class, because as soon as any of its properties are changed, the hash code changes, too.
[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx):

> As long as an object is used as a key in the Dictionary, it must not change in any way that affects its hash value.

The background of this is the following:
The dictionary retrieves and stores the hash code of the key at the time it is added. If the hash code of the key changed after that, it is different to the stored hash code and the object will not be seen as equal to the originally inserted key.

Comment: All his properties have private setters. So it might well be immutable. Still hashcode changing over time is my best guess on what the bug is.

Comment: Yes, I changed the Column object after additing to dictionary

Answer (score 2):

If `Dictionary<Column, string>` is right, then I would guess it's because the type `Column` is not compatible with how `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` checks equality - which is based on comparisons through `GetHashCode` and `Equals` - and my guess is that the `Column` type does not implement these.

Change the key type of the dictionary to something more suited to comparisons and equality.  Ideally use a string derived from the column's name.

### Update

Based on your code update, my guess is that something about the column has changed since it went into the dictionary that causes its 'live' hash code to change from what it was when it was first added to the Dictionary - so that could be any change in `Id`, `Name`, `Type`, `MainColumn` or `ChildColumns` that causes their HashCodes to change.

Comment: But shouldn't the dictionary check for reference equality unless otherwise specified? And shouldn't what he is passing into `ContainsKey` be the same object reference-wise to an existing key? *Especially* if he has not overridden the equality methods the check should return `true`.

Comment: @Jon - when I wrote this answer the OP hadn't put the code up with the `Column` implementation.

I don't believe reference equality is checked for explicitly - it's all done through IEqualityComparer which in this case falls back to the `Equals` override.  But first `GetHashCode` is used - only if two keys have the same hash code will `Equals` be called