# Using ContainsKey() when the key is not a simple primitive type

Tags: c#, dictionary

The ContainsKey() method of my Dictionary is not working - how do I "override GetHashCode()" to make it work?

Comment: What is your key type? what is its structure?

Comment: Is the key class one of your own types, or someone else's? Do you know how to override methods in general? See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx for some groundrules around GetHashCode.

Comment: We had this topic a few days ago. Basically, if your object is mutable and this is reflected by `GetHashCode` and `Equals`, it will fail. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437555/dictionary-containskey-misbehave-c/6437656#6437656) for more info.

Comment: "not a simple primitive type" is not detailed enough. When it's a class type, you don't have to do anything.

Answer (score 6):

You must override both `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()` to indicate equivalence. For example:

```
public sealed class MyType : IEquatable<MyType> {
    private readonly int foo;
    private readonly string bar;
    public int Foo { get { return foo; } }
    public string Bar { get { return bar; } }

    public MyType(int foo, string bar) {
        this.foo = foo; this.bar = bar;
    }
    public bool Equals(MyType other) {
       if(other == null) return false;
       return other.foo == this.foo && other.bar == this.bar;
    }
    public override bool Equals(object other) {
       return Equals(other as MyType);
    }
    public override int GetHashCode() {
       int result = 29;
       result = result * 13 + foo.GetHashCode();
       result = result * 13 + (bar == null ? 0 : bar.GetHashCode());
       return result;
    }
}
```

Note that `IEquatable<T>` is entirely optional, but is especially helpful for structs where it avoids a box. Note: it will make life saner if the parts that define equality are immutable.

Comment: shouldnt the bool Equals(object other) and GetHashCode be overrides

Comment: He doesn't necessarily have to override the methods, there is a Dictionary constructor overload where an equality comparer could be provided.

Comment: @Manatherin yes, they should - my bad!

Answer (score 3):

If you have no way to override the required methods (`GetHashCode()` and `Equals()`) on your items' class, there is a constructor for a dictionary where you may provide an `IEqualityComparer<T>` to perform the comparisons.  You could then provide the implementations for these methods without touching the original class.

```
class FooEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Foo>
{
    public bool Equals(Foo x, Foo y)
    {
        // implement Equals between x and y
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Foo obj)
    {
        // implement GetHashCode for obj
    }
}

class Foo
{
    // fields, properties, methods, etc.
}

// a dictionary that can use Foo's as keys
var myFooDict = new Dictionary<Foo, object>(new FooEqualityComparer())
{
    // ...
};
// use it like normal
if (myFooDict.ContainsKey(someFoo)) // the comparison will be handled by the comparer provided from the constructor
{
    // do stuff...
}
```